# Proper and easy way to connect nodes

Tags: node-editor, normals, bump

still learning Blender, I find myself dealing with textures. I downloaded models and among the .obj file, I also have a normal, bump, glow, diffuse and specular image. Now, in the shading panel, I connected the diffuse to the base color of the Principal BSDF, the specular to the specular of the Principal. I want to connect the other images the proper and correct way. Is there an easy way or a template I can follow teaching me how to correctly attach the nodes to the Principal? I checked the blender manual but it really doesn't assist me. Thank you.

Comment: The Specular map might be for the Roughness socket instead of the Specular one. Glow might be to mix an Emission if your object emits light. About the Normal and Bump: I guess you have either one or the other for one object, you need to plug them in a Normal map or Bump map, and plug those into the Normal of your Principled.

Comment: Hi moonboots, thanks for your quick reply. I have followed your input and it has made quite a difference. I will write these in a small .txt file so I can use it as my template.Cheers mate. Danny

Comment: Also, for all these maps, don't forget to switch the Image Texture node to Non-Color Data

Comment: It's questionable if specular map might be for roughness socket, only when someone named it incorrectly I suppose. Specular defines the intensity of reflection, roughness the sharpness, so they are different maps.

Comment: Hi moonboots, when I change it to non-color data, it removes the colors... I assume this is expected?